# How to use Java WTK project together with SVN?

Tags: java, svn, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I tried to create a project in WTK which I'm using for SVN commits. My problem is that every time I create the .jar package those .svn/ directories appear in it...

Is there any build script the Wireless Toolkit uses that I could modify to avoid including .svn folders to the packages? Or maybe better solution?

Comment: how do you build , which platform  ?  , I have used NB with SVN project it never do this for me !!

Comment: linux ubuntu 32 bit desktop 10.10 and I build using the ktoolbar. But I'm now working on a command line based solution like this one: http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/jme.htm#MIDlet-WTK-Kommandozeile

Answer (score 1):

You can build an [Ant script](http://ant.apache.org/) to package explicitly the directories you need using the [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html). Ant also includes an [SVN extension](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html) to allow exporting a clean tree without the .svn files. Ant by default excludes .svn directories as noted [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html).